# Dividing a graph to triple-vertices graphs such the sum of weights of edges is minimized

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I want to divide a graph to subgraphs that each subgraph made from maximum 3 vertices and sum of weight of edges is minimized, the main graph is complete ( have all possible edges ), and edges  are weighted.
the main problem that i want to solve is finding close three threes points on a map.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How good (or bad) did it work? And please pick only *one* language.

Comment: i searching about this problem and i think this is NP-Complete problem, but the input that i want in worst case is not more than 20 vertex, i hope there is any way to do job a little clean i read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194519/dividing-a-graph-in-three-parts-such-the-maximum-of-the-sum-of-weights-of-the-th) but not help enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this problem is NP-Complete. It's called the [minimum k-cut problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut).

Try to take a look at this [article](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~hassin/k_cut_00.pdf). It talks about approximation algorithms to solve such problems.